# $2 blank string not matched

Tags: shell, match, zsh

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

doit() {
    if [[ "$2" = "start" ]]; then
        for loc in $(cat all-doc); do
            if ! screen -list | grep -q My-$loc; then
                screen -dmS My-$loc /home/Server -f /home/$loc.cfg
            fi
        done
    elif [[ "$2" = "stop" ]]; then
        for loc in $(cat all-doc); do
            if screen -list | grep -q My-$loc; then
                pkill -f My-$loc;
            fi
        done
    else
        echo "Option: ERROR..."
    fi
}

nothing() {
    if [[ "$2" = "start" ]]; then
        echo "Option: 1"
    elif [[ "$1" = "stop" ]]; then
        echo "Option: 2"
    else
        echo "Option: 3"
    fi
}

case "$2" in
    start)
           "$1" "$2";
           ;;
    stop)
           "$1" "$2";
           ;;
    restart)
           restart;
           ;;
    *)
           echo "Usage: $0 {doit|nothing} {start|stop|restart}"
           exit 1
           ;;
esac

exit 0
```

I try to debug my script and this is the debug output with -x option.

> Output:

```
./script.sh:33> case start (start)
./script.sh:35> doit start
doit:1> [[ '' = start ]]
doit:7> [[ '' = stop ]]
doit:14> echo 'Option: ERROR...'
Option: ERROR...
./script.sh:49> exit 0
```

I dont know why this happend but seems $2 get blank string `[[ '' = start ]]` and `[[ '' = stop ]]` im new in shell scripts and im try to do somthing for my game server, i got confuesed.

Comment: I assume $2 is in your function the first argument ($1).

Comment: But i dont want somthing like `./script.sh  start doit` i need  exactly `./script.sh doit start` @Cyrus

Comment: Add this to both of your functions: `echo "1: $1 2: $2"`

Comment: @Cyrus Output: for ./script doit start ```doit:1> echo '1: start 2: '
1: start 2:
doit:2> [[ '' = start ]]
doit:8> [[ '' = stop ]]
doit:15> echo 'Option: ERROR...'
ption: ERROR...
./script.sh:52> exit 0```

Comment: Yes. It is exactly as I indicated in my first comment.

Comment: How fix it for `./script.sh doit start`?

Comment: Replace $2 in both functions with $1.

Comment: `Replace $2 in both functions with $1` i did it from your first comment and its work but the problem is "else" in both function did not work, output : `./script doit starrrrrrrr` ```./script.sh:36> case star (start)
./script.sh:36> case starrrrrrrr (stop)
./script.sh:36> case starrrrrrrr (restart)
./script.sh:36> case starrrrrrrr (*)
./script.sh:47> echo 'Usage: ./teeball.sh {start|stop|restart}'
sage: ./script.sh {start|stop|restart}
./script.sh:48> exit 1```

Comment: ```else echo "Option: ERROR..."``` not work for example `./script.sh doit test` @Cyrus

Comment: I believe this has nothing to do with your original question. Start a new question.

Comment: Ok , but i must waiting 90minuts for making another question its a lot of time. @Cyrus